# How to connect a Dragon32 to a HD TV?

Tags: connector

The Welsh computer has a coax output and a resolution of 256x192, can I expect this to display at all on my Philips 50" 4K TV using the same input?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Dragon 32 has two display outputs.  One is a UHF analogue TV signal, which will work if your TV has an analogue-capable tuner.  The other is a composite video output on a DIN socket, which you can wire up a cable for with a little effort; most good TVs have a composite video input somewhere.

Both will use PAL-I video timings.  These are normally supported by TVs, except possibly if they were sold in the US.